# Cant apply color theme to one frame in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, themes, customization

My `.emacs` file is [here](http://pastie.org/1003551). I want the theme to change when I am in `shell-mode`. But what happens is that the theme gets applied to all the windows. I set the variable `color-theme-is-global` to `nil`, but the problem still persists.

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'color-theme-monokai-terminal)
(set-variable 'color-theme-is-global nil)
```

These are the corresponding lines in my `.emacs` file. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the scenario. Do you want a different theme for a frame in which you only run shell-mode?

Comment: Only shell mode. That is why I added the hook.

Answer (score 5):

I usually start Emacs as a daemon and then open frames as needed. I use different color themes for X frames and terminal frames like so:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)

(defun apply-color-theme (frame)
  "Apply color theme to a frame based on whether its a 'real'
   window or a console window."
  (select-frame frame)
  (if (window-system frame)
      (color-theme-tango)
    (color-theme-tango-black)))

(setq color-theme-is-global nil)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'apply-color-theme)
```

You can replace the `(if window-system ...)` part with your check for shell-script-mode and the color-theme-X parts with your favorite themes.

There is one downside to this: if you don't start Emacs as a deamon, the customization will only kick in after you create a second frame, the first one that pops up will have the standard theme.

Comment: The problem with this is that, I can't check the mode of the frame upon its creation. I could have made a frame earlier and now am opening shell-mode on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think your terminology is off: in emacs-speak `frame` means what people normally mean by `window` in a graphical environment. (That is, the thing that has the close, minimize and maximize buttons and a titlebar, etc, is the "frame".) Whereas the things that show up when you do a `C-x 3` (split-window) are called `windows`, and when you do something like `M-x shell-mode` you get a new `buffer`, which may or may not be in a new window.

Color themes are always frame-global (as far as I know, and it's certainly what the documentation suggests) the variable `color-theme-is-global` determines whether a single theme propagates *across frames*.

I'm thinking that the closest thing to what you want is something like (completely untested, probably broken):

```
(defun shell-mode-in-new-frame ()
    (interactive)
    (select-frame (make-frame))
    (color-theme-monokai-terminal)
    (shell-mode))
```

Although this does create a new frame, which *isn't* what you want.

Comment: My terminology was incorrect. I have edited it now. So there is no way a window can a different theme than the rest of the windows?

Comment: I've never tried, but I would imagine that it would be fairly difficult, and possibly impossible. There are a lot of variables that you need to set, and you'd need to set all of them buffer-local. And some of them are probably in the C sources and not buffer-localizeable. But I'm just guessing there. In my experience though most modes provide enough mode-specific faces. (Try M-x list-faces-display with shell-mode active, and look for the comint-* faces, which are [I'm pretty sure] what shell mode uses.)

Comment: I guess it is pretty difficult. Thanks for making me ask the right question though. The way you are suggesting, I would be able to partly change the shell-mode buffer, but not completely.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's conceptually possible that every important face (which I didn't say before but "face" is emacs' way of saying "text-color") *can* be made buffer-local, in which case it's just a matter of doing something like (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook (lambda () (setq (make-local-variable background-color) "new-color") (setq (make-local-variable "something else") "new-color"))) for every face you care about. Which, you know, is tedious but possible. Maybe try doing that for one or two faces that you care about at a time, setting them to the values in the color theme that you want?